# Move folders and contents with Powershell

Tags: powershell

OK, trying to copy folders and contents from a UNC path (shared drive) to another UNC path (NAS) based on date (Before 01 Jan 2015). Yes I know the code says 2017 but once I get it working on test then I'll change the date and run on prod.

```
#Original file path
$path = "UNC Path"
#Destination file path
$destination = "Different UNC Path"
#It makes a filelist of what's inside the $path path
Foreach($file in (Get-ChildItem $path)) { 
#If the lastwrite time is before the given date
If($file.LastWriteTime -lt "01/01/2017") { 
#It copies the file to the destination
Copy-Item -Path $file.fullname -Destination $destination -Force } }
```

It copies the contents of folders fine but not the folders. I think I'm missing a -recurse but putting it after Get-ChildItem $path didn't work.

I plan to get this working then add a Remove-Item line to remove all the old items from the file server.

Thoughts? Suggestions of better ways to accomplish this?

Thanks,

Comment: just invoke robocopy

Answer (score 0):

I think you're just missing the `-Recurse` from `Get-ChildItem`, but I would do it like so:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Recurse `
| Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -lt '2017-01-01' } `
| ForEach-Object {
    Copy-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination ($_.FullName.Replace($source,$destination)) -Force;
}
```

If you've got hidden or system files to copy, you'll also want the `-Force` parameter on `Get-ChildItem`.

Actually, you might need to do this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Recurse `
| Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -lt '2017-01-01' } `
| ForEach-Object {
    if ($_.PSIsContainer -and !(Test-Path($_.FullName.Replace($source,$destination)) {
        mkdir ($_.FullName.Replace($source,$destination));
    }
    else {
        Copy-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination ($_.FullName.Replace($source,$destination)) -Force;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a start but two things: It's flattening out the file structure and there are a couple of file names that are too long. The file names I don't rally care but I'd rather not flatten the folder structure.

Comment: @tkiuntke Oh, of course.  I forgot that part!  See my corrected code.  As far as too long, you'd have to use some other tool.  PowerShell is based on C#, and C# is limited to the .Net Framework, and that doesn't use any of the long path name stuff that the WinAPI allows (i.e., `\\?\....`).  You'd have to use Robocopy or some similar tool that supports long path names.

Comment: @tkiuntke I'm a little surprised it's throwing errors if you're using UNC paths, though.  I thought those worked.